# True minimizing for another application

Tags: c#, minimize

I just want to do real minimized, all public codes are not minimizing in right way! It just minimize it as shown, but not minimize like if I click on Minimize button. How did I know that? Or what benefit will I get from that? When I press on minimize button, it reduce from CPU usage! (It's a game anyway.)

My code is :

```
    [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    List<int> ProcIDs = new List<int>();
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (process.ProcessName == "League of Legends")
            {
               // MinimizeWindow((IntPtr)hProcess);
                if (!ProcIDs.Contains(process.Id))
                {
                    IntPtr hProcess = GetProcessWindow(process.Id);
                    ProcIDs.Add(process.Id);
                    PostMessage(hProcess, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MINIMIZE, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }
        }
}
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
    const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
```

I also tried other methods and it does the same, just minimize as show, but not real minimize! :)

Comment: What do you meant by *real minimized*?

Comment: You could just run LoL in fullscreen, ALT-TABbing will minimize it to the taskbar (it does on my notebook, at least). Also, check if there is an option regarding keeping sound playing while in background (I can't remember), it could drop the load on the system

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, When i minimized to get an action which reduce CPU (De-active it)! :)

Comment: @Alex, I'm talking about 10-30 Client "window" at the same PC! :D So i can't ULT + Tab! :) Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Uhm... Maybe some more insight of the context of your code is needed, because to minimize many windows you could simply press WIN+D (actually, this would minimize everything that can be minimized ... and then some)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, WindowShowStyle nCmdShow);
```

with window style as ShowMinimized = 2,

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow

Comment: Tried it before.. The same!

Comment: In the link shared you have few other values for WindowShowStyle like 
Minimize = 6,
Have you tried other values as well?

Comment: No just ShowMinimized! :), give me time to try, because i'm scanning my PC now, so it's lagy, can't do anything!

Comment: Well I tried all, none of them works.. all are the same, it really make it not active, but still didn't change CPU

Comment: Just because an application is minimized, doesn't mean its thread stops running. @ChilakaUmesh has provided the correct answer to your question as stated. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this is exactly what happens when you click the minimize button.